# Brand personality and social media preference data

Tags: data-request, machine-learning, social-media

Where can I find a data set which predicts brand personality ([Anbang 2016](https://www.aaai.org/ocs/index.php/ICWSM/ICWSM16/paper/view/13078)) from the social media data preferences e.g. Twitter

I'm planning to improve on the methods of the above paper.